# Powershell - Files not older than

Tags: search, powershell, time

I´m trying to make a Powershell script that reports if there´s a file not older than x hours which contains some string pattern. I made this:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Folder -recurse | Select-String -pattern "err" | group path | select name | Where {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddHours(-12)}
```

Problem is that the last part of code which should select only files younger than x hours does not work - shows no files. When I change -gt to -lt it shows every file in the folder which contains pattern including younger than defined hours.

Does anyone has a solution please?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pipeline is in the wrong order.  You are piping a collection of strings to `Group-Object`, which pipes a different collection to `Select-Object`, etc.  Your call to `Where-Object` is receiving the output of `Select-Object`, which is a collection of `PSCustomObject`s.

What you want is to pipe the file objects themselves to `Where-Object`, and then pass *those* file objects down the pipeline:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Folder -recurse |
    Where {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddHours(-12)} |
    Select-String -pattern "err" | group path | select name
```

Comment: @Joey `Select-String` doesn't convert FileInfo objects to strings -- it searches the contents of the files.  Based on the code posted, Ziklop is searching for the string 'err' in files less than 12 hours old.

Comment: Eep, sorry. That's what I get for never using that cmdlet. You're right.